# Jmeter __RequestVerificationToken extracting problem

Tags: jmeter

I recording login with jmeter. I test with 1 user but jmeter cannot login because of __VerificationToken.

I parsed token with CSS Selector Extractor

[image]

[image]

I'm sure the token has been moved in the cookie.

But I saw two __VerificationToken. Error return request:

```
GET data:
Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
__RequestVerificationToken=hYTIRJryyxCBfF7vYlAnkPSM-JB0o-        Zp41pqFGk30cLyPAehA22k69VOU3NhY-abVbxuEZDgZHnF-bTFHf_4g1HwkuQ1; 
__RequestVerificationToken=${token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing what parameters and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) does real browser send, however it seems you're doing something weird.

1. You shouldn't manually create the `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie as it seems to be properly handled by the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
2. Given you have the token value already stored in the HTTP Cookie Manager there is no need to extract it, if you need to send it as the parameter in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```

   and once you restart JMeter to pick up the property you will be able to access the token value as `${COOKIE___RequestVerificationToken}` where required

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)